# Big blue button dev instance stuck at 0 % loading

Tags: nginx, virtualbox, bigbluebutton

I installed big blue button 0.9 on a Virtual box running Ubuntu 14.04 on a windows 7 host machine. It runs fine.

Then when I try to setup the dev enviroment of big blue button, it doens't load the client and is stuck at 0%.It give the response as *Could not find conference*

This is what  I get [image]

Things I have tried:

- I tried rebuilding with `ant`, it says `BUILD SUCCESFULL`
- I changed the config.xml file to match 192.168.11.88 i.e. the IP nginx is running on
- Also ran the command `sudo bbb-conf --setip 192.168.11.88`

In the Chrome console, it tells me that `GET` requests to IP `10.0.2.15` fail with `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

PS: This was running fine until I changed my virtual box network adapter setting form NAT to Bridge adapter

Comment: Did you run `bbb-conf setip` or `bbb-conf --setip`? Mind the `--`. I expect that this solves the problem.

Comment: Yes I did use --setip <IP>, I edited the question, I had a clean restart and now I get the above screen where is says "Could not find conference" in the response XML

Comment: I manually change some IPs in bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml and now it seems to work

Comment: not == now? `bbb-conf --setip` does AFAIK exactly this.

Comment: sorry for the typo ,also I am pretty sure I did do setip ,not sure why it default back to the original IP address

Comment: Did you run `bbb-conf` once more without the `--setip` parameter? IIRC years ago when I used it, this resetted to the auto-detected IP.